# How to load more comments without refreshing the browser

Tags: php, jquery

Am working on comment system, but am stuck here, after loading my PHP on my browser, it shows me exactly 2 comments that I want to see, when I click the link it fetches the other 2 comments as I programmed it on jQuery, but after that the button disappears and I cant load more comments.

Please help!

Here is my code,

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var commentCount = 2;
 $("button").click(function() {
 commentCount = commentCount + 2;
 $("#comments").load("2.php", {
 commentNewCount: commentCount

 });
 });

 });

</script>
<body>
<div id="comments">
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<div class="media response-info">
<div class="media-left response-text-left">
<a href="#">
<img class="media-object" src="images/c1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></a></h5>
</div>
<div class="media-body response-text-right">
 <p><?php  echo $row['message']; ?></p>
 <ul>
 <li><?php echo $row['time']; ?> </li>
 <li><a href="single.html">Reply</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>

<?php   }

} else {
    echo "there are no comments!";
}
?>
<button>More comments</button>

</body>
```

and this down here is my load-coments.php (i decided to call it 2.php)

```
<?php 
include 'include/dbconnect.php';
$commentNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id LIMIT $commentNewCount";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<div class="media response-info">
<div class="media-left response-text-left">
<a href="#">
<img class="media-object" src="images/c1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></a></h5>
</div>
<div class="media-body response-text-right">
<p><?php  echo $row['message']; ?></p>
<ul>
<li><?php echo $row['time']; ?> </li>
<li><a href="single.html">Reply</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<?php   }

} else {
    echo "there are no comments!";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use web-socket(proper way) for this purpose that will push new comment to browser automatically, anyways your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I have to learn on that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "button disappears"?. The load function of jquery replaces the html with the recieved html so maybe your button is in the div you're replacing. It's hard to debug your code because of the lack of indents.

Comment: It means after clicking the load button, it loads the seconds two row then the button cease to exist on the page, so no more loading of the comments, am stuck there

Comment: You mean i have to place the button in the load-comments.php ? as it is the one which fetches the comments

Comment: By calling "load" on $("#comments") your replace the content of "#comments". Make sure youre button is not inside that division.